NIntegrate: variable is not a valid limit of integration
I have a function $F(z_h)$ given by,
$$F(z_h) = \int^{\infty}_{z_h} s(y) T'(y) dy$$
where $T \equiv T(z_h), T' \equiv T'(z_h), s \equiv s(z_h)$, which means they're all functions of $z_h$. Their expressions are all written in the code below. However, for the definition of $F$ I have to write $s$ and $T'$ in terms of a dummy variable to do an integration, where the lower limit is $z_h$. When I do this and evaluate, say $F(10)$, it gives me an error. I know this issue has something to do with the syntax and has seen this post (272204) but I'm not sure how to resolve it. Any guidance?
Note: In the code I have written T[m,zh], Tp[m,zh], F[m,zh] which is also a function of m, but this is just my convention, I could have declared the fixed value m write from the start, the one that changes is zh.
Clear["Global`*"]
ag = 8;
pg = 8;
wp = 10;
a = 4.046;
b = 0.01613;
c = 0.227;
A[z_] := -a Log[b z^2 + 1]
Ap[z_] := D[A[z], z]
int1[zh_] := NIntegrate[y^3 Exp[-3 A[y]], {y, 0, zh}];
int2[zh_] := NIntegrate[y^3 Exp[-3 A[y] + c y^2], {y, 0, zh}];

s[zh_] := Exp[3 A[zh]]/(4 zh^3);
T[m_, zh_] := ((zh^3 Exp[-3 A[zh]])/(4 Pi int1[zh])) (1 - ((2 c m^2)/(1 - Exp[c zh^2])^2) (Exp[c zh^2] int1[zh] - int2[zh]));
Tp[m_, zh_] := (((3 zh^2 Exp[-3 A[zh]] - 3 Ap[zh] zh^3 Exp[-3 A[zh]]) int1[zh] - zh^6 Exp[-6 A[zh]])/(4 Pi int1[zh] int1[zh])) (1 - ((2 c m^2)/(1 - Exp[c zh^2])^2) (Exp[c zh^2] int1[zh] - int2[zh])) - 2 c m^2 ((zh^3 Exp[-3 A[zh]])/(4 Pi int1[zh])) (((2 c zh Exp[c zh^2] int1[zh]) (1 - Exp[c zh^2])^2 + 4 c zh Exp[c zh^2] (1 - Exp[c zh^2]) (Exp[c zh^2] int1[zh] - int2[zh]))/(1 - Exp[c zh^2])^4);
F[m_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[s[y] Tp[m, y], {y, zh, Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 6, WorkingPrecision -> 10]

F[0.1, 10]

NIntegrate::nlim: y = y is not a valid limit of integration.
NIntegrate::nlim: y = y is not a valid limit of integration.
NIntegrate::nlim: y = y is not a valid limit of integration.
General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::nlim will be suppressed during this calculation.
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand (((-y^6 (1+Times[<<2>>])^24.276+(<<1>>+3 <<1>> <<1>>) <<1>>) (<<1>>))/(4 \[Pi] NIntegrate[y^3 Exp[<<1>>],<<1>>]^2)-(<<22>> <<2>> (<<1>>+<<1>>))/((<<1>>)^4 <<10>>[<<1>>]))/(4 y^3 (1+0.01613 y^2)^12.138) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{\[Infinity],10.00000000}}.


replace int1[zh_] by int1[zh_?NumericQ] (and same for int2).

@AccidentalFourierTransform It worked, but why only for int1 and int2? How about the other functions?
